# Why does unique_ptr overload reset(pointer p = pointer()) and reset(nullptr_t)?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, overloading, unique-ptr

Accroding to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset,

```
void reset( pointer ptr = pointer() );

template< class U > 
void reset( U ) = delete;

void reset( std::nullptr_t p );
```

> 1) Given `current_ptr`, the pointer that was managed by `*this`, performs
>   the following actions, in this order:
>       Saves a copy of the current pointer `old_ptr = current_ptr`;
>       Overwrites the current pointer with the argument `current_ptr = ptr`;
>       If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object `if(old_ptr != nullptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr)`.
>
> 2) In the specialization for dynamic arrays, `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`,
>   this template member is provided to prevent using `reset()` with a
>   pointer to derived (which would result in undefined behavior with
>   arrays).
>
> 3) In the specialization for dynamic arrays, `std::unique_ptr<T[]>`, the
>   third overload is necessary to allow reset to `nullptr` (which would
>   otherwise be prohibited by the template overload). Equivalent to
>   `reset(pointer())`

Now that `reset(nullptr)` is equivalent to `reset(pointer())`, why does the latter exist?

If I want to reset an array form unique_ptr, why can I not just use `rest(pointer())`?

Comment: I'm actually finding the method `delete`ion more interesting...

Comment: Because it would be silly to have `p.reset(nullptr)` to be a compile error?

Comment: Note that `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` accepts `T *` and `T *` only as the pointer type for its constructor and for the `reset` method. Notably, **it does not accept pointers to types different from `T` even if they're convertible to pointers to `T`**. In other words: without that overload `p.reset(nullptr);` would not compile. That would be quite silly. (For the same reason, there's a `unique_ptr(nullptr_t)` ctor.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The

```
template< class U > 
void reset( U ) = delete;
```

would be chosen for a call with `nullptr` argument, if not for

```
void reset( std::nullptr_t p );
```

That's why it exists, to allow the call with `nullptr`.

---

Example (compile with `FIX` defined to suppress the compilation error):

```
#include <cstddef>      // std::nullptr_t

struct S
{
    void reset( char* ) {}

    template< class Type >
    void reset( Type ) = delete;

    #if FIX
    void reset( std::nullptr_t ) {}
    #endif
};

auto main() -> int
{
    S().reset( nullptr );    // Fails when FIX is not defined.
}
```

Comment: Why reset(nullptr) cannot be resolved to reset(pointer)? The #1 form is more specific than #2 form. So, I think, even if no #3 form, the overloading resolution can still work.

Comment: @xmllmx: the template is an exact match on type, while the non-template involves a conversion.

Answer (score 2):

`reset` ist implemented as

```
pointer old = this->ptr;
this->ptr= newPointer;
delete[] old;
```

The templated overload is deleted for arrays to prevent the following case

```
class foo{};
class bar : public foo {};

foo* managedPointer = new foo[3];
bar* newPointer = new bar[5];

foo* old = managedPointer;
managedPointer = newPointer;
delete[] old;
```

Which is undefined behavior. Section 5.3.5 paragraph 3:

> [...] In the second alternative (delete array) if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.

Since deleted functions still participate in overload resolution and `reset(U)` provide a better match for `nullptr` than `reset(pointer)` 
, there is an additional overload to to allow `reset(nullptr)`, which would otherwise give a compiler error and thus result in an inconsistent interface between array and pointer version.