# Why does std::unique_ptr need to be specialized for dynamic arrays?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, clang, template-specialization

I examined VC++ 2013 and clang 3.4 and found that both implemented `std::unique_ptr` as follows:

```
template<class T, class DeleterType = std::default_delete<T>>
class unique_ptr
{
    // ...
};

template<class T, class DeleterType>
class unique_ptr<T[], DeleterType>
{
    // ...
};
```

`std::default_delete` is able to determine whether T is an array type. So `std::unique_ptr` needn't to specialize itself to handle array case. Moreover, I cannot find any substantial differences between `class unique_ptr` and the specialized `class unique_ptr<T[], DeleterType>`, why is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is in constructors and `reset()` - `unique_ptr<T>` accepts any `X*` convertible to `T*`, while `unique_ptr<T[]>` only accepts a `T*`. Which makes sense, given the semantics and restrictions of arrays.

Also, `unique_ptr<T[]>` overloads `operator[]`, while `unique_ptr<T>` does not.

Comment: unique_ptr<T[]>'s ctors accept T* as its parameter, how does it prohibit type conversion. Say, A* can be converted to T*, and call unique_ptr<T[]>(new A[1])?

Comment: @xmllmx The standard has a note which says "One implementation technique is to create private templated overloads of these members." [See this recent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24359194/1782465) for exactly this discussion. Whoops, that's your own question... so, there's it's answered :-)

Comment: Also deleter differs -- `delete` vs `delete[]`?

Comment: @Yakk I believe that's the responsibility of `std::default_delete`.

Comment: @angew sure, but `unique_ptr<T>` uses one, while `unique_ptr<T[]>` uses another default deleter?

Comment: @Yakk `std::unique_ptr<U>` always uses `std::default_delete<U>`. Which of course means it uses a different one when `U` is `T[]`, but the unique pointer itself doesn't care.

Comment: @angew ah yes, that would be handled without specialization, got ya.