# Why does unique_ptr have a nullptr_t constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

It isn't clear to me what the benefits are.

If I have:

```
Foo* foo = nullptr;
std::unique_ptr<Foo> unique_foo(foo);
```

Is the nullptr_t constructor called in that situation? Or only if you do:

```
std::unique_ptr<Foo> unique_foo(nullptr);
```

Thanks!

There is some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24359194/why-does-unique-ptr-overload-resetpointer-p-pointer-and-resetnullptr-t) which is to allow you to passing in nullptr_t, otherwise it won't compile since it won't cast to type pointer. So my question may be why it doesn't cast?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A possible reason is that the `unique_ptr` constructor that takes a `unique_ptr::pointer` argument is `explicit`. This means that in the absence of the `unique_ptr(nullptr_t)` constructor, the following code would not compile.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> intp = nullptr;
```

Since a `unique_ptr` is intended to be a lightweight smart pointer that closely imitates raw pointer semantics, it is desirable to have the above code compile.

---

In your first example the `nullptr_t` constructor is not called because the type of the argument is `Foo*`, even though its value is `nullptr`.

Comment: If it's so important to closely imitate raw pointer semantics then why the explicit constructor?

Comment: @Brian: To avoid implicit conversion, such as in this case, `T *p = new T(); f(p);` wherein `f` takes `std::unique_ptr` which in turn means it takes the ownership of the resource implicitly **or rather accidentally**. This is bad because the programmer might not intended it. So the constructor is declared `explicit`, so as to force programmers to write `f(std::unique_ptr<T>(p));` if they want to transfer the ownership.

Comment: @Brian I agree with Nawaz. It could lead to accidental transfer of ownership, but that is not an issue in the `nullptr` case.

Comment: That makes sense on why the constructor is explicit. What about having nullptr_t 'automatically' be castable to type Foo*?

Comment: @Kyle it is automatically castable to type `Foo*`.  But that then requires an explicit conversion to `unique_ptr`, which is silly for a `nullptr` constant: there is no ownership transfer to guard against.

Comment: Oh, so it's essentially for cases that take in an `unique_ptr`, that you can pass in `nullptr` rather than `std::unique_ptr(nullptr)`. It is making `nullptr` work better (granted, a different meaning) then `Foo*`, not just bringing it to parity. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't std::unique_ptr<int> intp = nullptr; equivalent to std::unique_ptr<int> intp(nullptr); ? The later one works...

Answer (score 2):

The original proposal that lead to the constructor being added is [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2435.htm), and explains the use case: it's intended to make `if (p == 0)` compile. This works because in that comparison, the RHS of `==` is implicitly convertible to the type of `p`, because of the `nullptr` constructor.

Prior to that change, `unique_ptr` had an implicit conversion operator to a bool-ish type, so the comparison was valid. Merely changing that to a `explicit operator bool()` would have made the comparison invalid.

Answer (score 1):

A `Foo*` that happens to have a value of `0` is not type `nullptr_t`, it is the type `Foo*`. So, only passing `nullptr` uses the `nullptr_t` constructor.

Comment: So a related question (added an addendum to my question) is why is nullptr_t not castable to 0 of any type T*?